# Change style of hyperlinks

Tags: html, css

I am a total novice with coding, so please bear in mind.

I am updating a site via Wordpress and have buttons that link to places as well as other hyperlinks in the body.

I finally managed to change text color on the blue buttons to white, but this had the effect of changing the text colour of other links in body to white as well, which on a white background is a problem.

Element is defined as #content a {color: #ffffff}

How do change/add to the CSS theme file so that I can have different color for button text and a different colour for body links?

Site is www.dev.portland.co.za

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: show your code and explain what u want

Comment: Not quite sure how to explain, this is what I see      element.style {
}
#content a:hover {
    color: #405aa6;
}
#content a {
    color: #ffffff;
} and this <a target="_blank" href="http://www.dev.portland.co.za/quarry/quarry-quote-request/" id="thinkupshortcodesthinkup_builder_buttontheme1" class="button style1 themebutton small standard">ORDER NOW</a>

Comment: Please forgive me, I am completely new to this, so not quite sure where to go (in WordPress) to change/add element styles etc. I understand that I perhaps need to apply different classes to the different links, the question is how?

Comment: @לבני מלכה please see comments above. Any help is truly appreciated

Comment: add to your css file: `button{color:red}` It change **all** button text color and `a{color:blue}` chang **all** a text color

Comment: I thing you should read about css and selector